# GET method returns 500 Internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm new here so I have some question. I'm developing a web site, but there is some problem.
I have map with tags, that onclick invokes a function "getObject(this.alt)".

```
function getObjects(object){
console.log(object);
$.get("/sites/map/objects.php?t="+object, function(data) {
  $('#answer').html(data);
});
```

It executes script object.php were t= area tags alt attribute, the objects.php connects to MySql and returns objects row, but I get this kind of error:

```
GET http://some-site.com/sites/map/objects.php?t=some_object 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-latest.js:8706
```

Can you please help me? :)

This is the PHP code.
Object is alt atribute from area tag in HTML file. It gets this alt and from that returns DB row with this alt name.

```
<?php
$object = $_GET['t'];
echo $object;
$con=mysqli_connect("server_adr","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$con->set_charset("utf8");
if($object!='all'){
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM map WHERE `city`='$object' ORDER BY tips");
}
else{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM map ORDER BY tips"); 
}
$old_tips = '';
$old_city = ''; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $tips = $row['tips'];
  $city = $row['city'];
  if($old_tips!=$tips){
      echo '<strong>'.$tips.'</strong><br>';
  }
  if($old_city!=$city){
      echo $row['city'] . '<br>';
  }
  echo $row['title'] . ' - <a href="'.$row['web'].'">' . $row['web']. '</a>';
  echo "<br>";
  $old_tips = $row['tips'];
  $old_city = $row['city'];
  }
?>
```

And the WEB server info:

- Apache/2.2.21 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8q DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch SVN/1.7.1
- MySQL client version: 5.1.59
- PHP extension: mysql

Comment: "500 (Internal **Server** Error)" - The issue is in the PHP. Check your PHP logs for errors then fix them.

Comment: problem with your server side code

Comment: Post your php code here and or attach the `object` detail information

Comment: Check your code in `objects.php` Error has nothing to do with your javascript code.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: Actualy I cant see log, because I just have premmisions on my IP address.

Comment: probably mysqli is not installed on your server, make sure you have installed mysqli

Comment: Isn't this the mysql? MySQL client version: 5.1.59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_connect` throws exception if mysqli module not installed or enabled. You'd activate this module in the `php` extions file

OR if your database is a mysql database and not mysqli, 
try to change from `mysqli` to `mysql` in your php code file

Comment: The PHP extension shows mysql, but when I change mysqli to mysql nothing changes.

Comment: No! What you need to do in your PHP extentions file is TO UNCOMMENT THE LINE WHERE `mysqli` is. OR if you are using a mysql database, the function to use in your php file is `mysql_...` instead of `mysqli_...`

Comment: Sorry, that was what I ment. Extension shows `mysql` and the changes I made in my php file. So now I something did that mysql_error() shows  `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61`  I think better than `Internal Server Error`. I cant get to server configuraton, is there another way to resolve this?

Comment: Cheking out `mysql_connect()` I have new error. `Access denied for user 'user'@'multisite' (using password: YES)` Why multisite? And this `user` has `WRITE` `READ` and all needed premissions. Whats wrong with my SQL?

Comment: what is you dbms? Are you using `mysql` or `mysqli` ?

Comment: PHP extension: `mysql`

Comment: Done, I will post my answer tomorrow. Thanks everybody for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on the php.

Add this to the top of your php script:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
```

Then check the log:

```
tail -f /tmp/php-error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved problem like this.
Cheked the PHP extension, changed `mysqli_...` to `mysql_...` 
Cheked the SQL user privilegies and changed them to be suitable to my problem.
And I had database address written "localhost" because it runs on other server, not mine but when given to `mysql_connect()` the address like in IP, then the connection established right.
And whola it worked, thanks everybody for help. :)

Now it looks something like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("db_addr","sql_user","password");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
{
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connection successfully <br>";

mysql_select_db("database_name");
mysql_set_charset('utf8' , $connection);
```